# How to modify this problem into a MultiThreading N-Queens problem?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to modify Main.java and HillClimbingSearch.java so that we can create several threads each running one instance of HillClimbingSearch.

Each thread will start from a randomly selected point in the search space and the threads will explore different parts of the search space concurrently until one of them finds a solution. This can considerably improve the time required to find a solution for large values of n (e.g., n > 40).
In order to to do the solution a **ThreadGroup** is to be created in order to keep track of all your threads. We need stop all the threads as soon as one of them finds a solution.

```
 //Program to implement Hill Climbing with random restart to solve N-queens problem
 import java.util.Random;


public class HillClimbingSearch{ 
private int n ;
private int heuristic = 0;
private int presentHeuristic;
private NQueen[] finalSolution;

public  HillClimbingSearch (int size) {
    n = size;   
    finalSolution = null;
}

public NQueen[] getFinalSolution() {
    return finalSolution;
}

//Method to create a new random board
public NQueen[] generateBoard() {
    NQueen[] startBoard = new NQueen[n];
    Random rndm = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        startBoard[i] = new NQueen(rndm.nextInt(n), i);
    }
    return startBoard;
}

//Method to print the Current State
public  void printState (NQueen[] state) {
    //Creating temporary board from the present board
    int[][] tempBoard = new int[n][n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        //Get the positions of Queen from the Present board and set those positions as 1 in temp board
        tempBoard[state[i].getRow()][state[i].getColumn()]=1;
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j= 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(tempBoard[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Method to find Heuristics of a state
public  int findHeuristic (NQueen[] state) {
    int heuristic = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< state.length; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<state.length; j++ ) {
            if (state[i].ifConflict(state[j])) {
                heuristic++;
            }
        }
    }
    return heuristic;
}

// Method to get the next board with lower heuristic
public NQueen[] nextBoard (NQueen[] presentBoard) {
    NQueen[] nextBoard = new NQueen[n];
    NQueen[] tmpBoard = new NQueen[n];
    int presentHeuristic = findHeuristic(presentBoard);
    int bestHeuristic = presentHeuristic;
    int tempH;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        //  Copy present board as best board and temp board
        nextBoard[i] = new NQueen(presentBoard[i].getRow(), presentBoard[i].getColumn());
        tmpBoard[i] = nextBoard[i];
    }
    //  Iterate each column
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (i>0)
            tmpBoard[i-1] = new NQueen (presentBoard[i-1].getRow(), presentBoard[i-1].getColumn());
        tmpBoard[i] = new NQueen (0, tmpBoard[i].getColumn());
        //  Iterate each row
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            //Get the heuristic
            tempH = findHeuristic(tmpBoard);
            //Check if temp board better than best board
            if (tempH < bestHeuristic) {
                bestHeuristic = tempH;
                //  Copy the temp board as best board
                for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                    nextBoard[k] = new NQueen(tmpBoard[k].getRow(), tmpBoard[k].getColumn());
                }
            }
            //Move the queen
            if (tmpBoard[i].getRow()!=n-1)
                tmpBoard[i].move();
        }
    }
    //Check whether the present bord and the best board found have same heuristic
    //Then randomly generate new board and assign it to best board
    if (bestHeuristic == presentHeuristic) {
        nextBoard = generateBoard();
        heuristic = findHeuristic(nextBoard);
    } else
        heuristic = bestHeuristic;
    return nextBoard;
}

public void runSearch(){

    NQueen[] presentBoard = generateBoard();
    presentHeuristic = findHeuristic(presentBoard);
    // test if the present board is the solution board
    while (presentHeuristic != 0) {
        //  Get the next board
       // printState(presentBoard);
        presentBoard = nextBoard(presentBoard);
        presentHeuristic  = heuristic;
    }
    finalSolution = presentBoard;
}


}

public class Main {




public static void main(String[] args) {


        int n = 0; 
        try (Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Enter the number of Queens :");
                n = s.nextInt();
                if ( n == 2 || n ==3) {
                    System.out.println("No Solution possible for "+ n +" Queens. Please enter another number");
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        long timestamp1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Solution to "+ n +" queens using hill climbing search:");

        HillClimbingSearch hcs = new HillClimbingSearch(n);

        hcs.runSearch();

        if (hcs.getFinalSolution() != null)
            hcs.printState(hcs.getFinalSolution());



        //Printing the solution
        long timestamp2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long timeDiff = timestamp2 - timestamp1;
        System.out.println("Execution Time: "+timeDiff+" ms");


    }
}


//Class for N-queens Problem
public class NQueen {
private int row;
private int column;

public NQueen(int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

public void move () {
    row++;
}

public boolean ifConflict(NQueen q){
    //  Check rows and columns
    if(row == q.getRow() || column == q.getColumn())
        return true;
        //  Check diagonals
    else if(Math.abs(column-q.getColumn()) == Math.abs(row-q.getRow()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). There are a number of different ways to configure these. I've not tested them all. But I've made good use of [newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

One key to using them is having some sort of loose coupling mechanism in place. A class for collecting and comparing results from the multiple threads should use a concurrent collection of some sort for holding these results. Then, threads could post there without blocking.

I had good luck using a [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://ConcurrentSkipListSet), where I wrote a custom class to hold a given thread's result, with `Comparable` implemented, as the type for the Set. Seems like that would be a good choice, as the "best solution" would automatically jump to the head of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, maybe you should do some algorithm-searching:  you will discover that the N-Queens problem can be very trivially solved with the right algorithm.  Thirty years or so ago, BYTE magazine had an article which described an elegant solution implemented in about forty lines of BASIC.

*Hint:* Since only one queen can ever be in any column of the chessboard, the board was represented by a *one-dimensional* array, one per column.  The solution-finder wasn't even recursive and it simply printed the whole solution space out in less than a second ... on the hardware of the day.